# How can I convert an IFO file to play on youtube?

Tags: dvd, youtube

Is there a free way to convert an IFO file to play on youtube? I have a very short clip that I need to load to our website.

Answer (score 2):

IFO files do not contain any video.  They are part of standard DVD structure, but they are not video files.

Comment: "IFO Files give the player important navigational information, like where a chapter starts, where a certain audio or subtitle stream is located, etc. This is the reason why it's only possible to rip certain parts of a movie (like a chapter) with a ripper which can read this files."

http://www.doom9.org/index.html?/dvd-structure.htm

Comment: It's the VOB files that contain the video.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer without being positive if it will handle it, but for almost all video conversions, free and cross platform I love [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/)